# Moving a Wordpress site created by a non-cooperative firm

Tags: wordpress, migration, website

My boss hired a firm to create a website for an organization.   My boss knowing very little about computers/IT in general just assumed that they would create a site and then hand it over to us and we would do the hosting.  But once we were ready to "take delivery" of the site they said that they assumed from the beginning that they would be hosting the site, and the cost is $70/month.  Otherwise if not, that is if we or whoever else hosts the site then they will need to write a manual and description for $2500.

Although I have done this before in the past, to migrate a Wordpress site from one host to another is a fairly easy task correct?  There are numerous guides and it is just a matter of copying the content files and database, change the URL links etc... So besides handing over the files there should be nothing else for them to do.  Why would they need to write a manual and description?  And that should be true regardless of how complex (i.e. fancy plug-ins etc) the website is?  Can someone confirm this or not?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think it really depends on how they have built the site.  They *could* have used complicated components, which requires very specific setup.  When you build websites at scale, you can get certain economies with that.  They could be hosting 100 sites on the same server, so unpicking the configurations, and creating a generic one for you, could take some time.  Especially if they assume they need to provide instructions on how to install Linux, configure apache/nginx, how to keep wordpress updated, how to update the theme, when wordpress updates...

Comment: In reality, I don't think they *have* to handover the source code, if that was not what was in the contract.  This is more of a legal/contract issue.  One thing to keep in mind: have you worked out who is going to perform the weekly/monthly maintenance on the website going forward, to make sure the website/webserver is kept up to date, so isn't vulnerable to exploits?